# c# Call List from one form into another

Tags: c#, forms, list, class

first post of mine here and hoping to get a little bit of help for a problem i seem to can't figure out. For an assignment I am supposed to do, I need to create a game with 2 player attacking each other. I want the users to be able to upgrade their stats after each round, but upgrade them in a form separate from the game form (well call them UpgradeForm and GameForm, respectively).

I am keeping the majority of the players' data in class Helicopters in a List (List Heli = new List();) My biggest problem is trying to call that list from the GameForm into my UpgradeForm. Here is what I've got for code so far:

```
public partial class GameForm : Form
{
   public List<Helicopter> Heli = new List<Helicopter>();

   private void GameForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        Heli.Add(new Helicopter(1, this));//give helicopter player # and set a form variable to the current GameForm
        Heli.Add(new Helicopter(2, this));
   }

   private void GameForm_to_UpgradeForm()
   {
       newForm = true;
       UpgradeForm UF = new UpgradeForm(this);
       UF.Show();
       FormProvider.GameForm.Hide();
       //FormProvider is how i'm calling my GameForm. 
       //Shouldn't have an effect on what I'm trying to do.
   }
}
```

In my UpgradeForm:

```
public partial class UpgradeForm : Form
{
    private GameForm gF;
    List<Helicopter> HeliList = new List<Helicopter>();

    public UpgradeForm(GameForm gForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.gF = gForm;
        HeliList = this.gF.Heli;
    }
}
```

However, I get an error:
"Error  1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less accessible than field 'Project.GameForm.Heli'

What am i doing wrong, and what do i need to fix? Will post the code to FormProvider class if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the exception? Clearly `Heli` needs to be public.

Comment: apparently, thats what was needed. duh. Thanks for pointing out my obvious mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modifyyour UpgradeForm:

```
public partial class UpgradeForm : Form
{
    private GameForm gF;
    List<Helicopter> HeliList = new List<Helicopter>();

    public UpgradeForm(List<Helicopter> list)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HeliList.AddRange(list);
    }
}
```

and from the GameFprm class:

```
private void GameForm_to_UpgradeForm()
{
   newForm = true;
   UpgradeForm UF = new UpgradeForm(Heli);
   UF.Show();
   FormProvider.GameForm.Hide();
}
```

"What am i doing wrong, and what do i need to fix?"

1. please don't pass an object of an ENTIRE form just for a list with 2 items
2. make your own classes and make instances of them without involving UI components

Comment: so what exactly should i do then? I've been looking for a way to share the Heli List in my Game form in my upgrade form, and cant figure out how.